# Excel DNA IntelliSense stopped working suddenly

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-dna

We have used Excel DNA IntelliSense for creating UDFs in our VSTO application and was running fine. Suddenly the IntelliSense stopped working. They work when we run the code through Visual Studio but fails to, when Excel is running separately.

I have included the code for installation of IntelliSense as guided here - [UsageInstruction](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/IntelliSense/wiki/Usage-Instructions). My understanding so far is that the AutoOpen() does not hit in order to install the IntelliSense.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!